# How do I make one network settings the default

Tags: networking

I have two named Ethernet settings in my Network Connections: one for normal Internet access, one for lab work where everything is static IP addresses.  I would like the Internet settings to be "default", but in fact every time I log in, the static IP settings are selected and I have to manually choose the other one.  How do I choose which one to be the default?

Answer (score 2):

In `terminal`, type `nm-connection-editor`, and select the desired primary ethernet connection profile, and set the priority to 1...

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the delay.  My system's nm-connection-editor does not present the priority option.  I compromised by turning off the "Connect automatically" option on the other network.

Comment: @RadlyEel what version Ubuntu?

Comment: thanks, funny how it was so easy yet i wasted 30mins!